# How can I reuse an existing API (mongo + passport-local) with my react-native project?

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a existing API (node + mongo + passport-local) that I have been using for a while.  I have a `Users` model and `Posts` model.  Using postman, I can register, login, and create/edit/delete posts.

The `Users` model contains `userid`, `username`, `displayname`, and of course password that passport automatically salts/hashes.

The `Posts` model has `postid`, `userid`, `title`, `text`, and `creationdate`.

I want to use this existing set up in my react-native app.  So, if I have this API running on localhost:9000 or something, and I want to register users on it as well as any new posts made by a logged in user, is that possible?

I was hoping to use redux to manage my user state.  The user object will initialize as null, so if it is null, show the login page.  Ignoring registration for now, so if the user puts in a username/password and hits submit, the userLogin action will fire that makes a POST to `localhost:9000/login` with the username/pass and I get the response back which gives me the username and display name.  User object is updated, and since it exists the user will be routed to the main app page.

I've been trying to learn about user authentication for react-native apps but the things I've found so far have been extremely confusing.  I tried using parse but could not get it to work after spending 2 hours on it and honestly I don't even understand it.  I just want to be able to use my local API and test locally.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fetch to do 'GET' and 'POST' requests. Username and password go into the body object. For example:

```
fetch('http://localhost:9000/login, {
      method: 'POST',
      crossOrigin: true,
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        password: pw
      })
}).then((r) => {r.json()})
.then((result) => {... do something with the result})
```

Since fetch returns a promise, you get the result in the 'then' statement.

Based on the response you can update the state in your stores to 'logged in' our 'logged out'.

Comment: thank you frederick.  I have not been able to access computer for some days but today I will try this and report to you the results.  Thanks

Comment: @Frederick, how can I use login with FB/Google in the same way?